# How to edit output rows from awk with defined position?

Tags: string, bash, awk, printing, row

Is there a way how to solve this?

I have a bash script, which creates .dat and .log file from source files.
I'm using `awk` with print and position what I need to print. The problem is with the last position - ID2 (lower). It should be just `\*[0-9]{3}\*#`, but in some cases there is a string before `[0-9]{12}\[00]\>`.
Then row looks for example like this:

```
2020-01-11 01:01:01;test;test123;123456789123[00]>*123*#
```

What I need is remove the string before in a file:

```
2020-01-11 01:01:01;test;test123;*123*#
```

File structure:

```
YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS;string;ID1;ID2
```

I will be happy for any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$NF=substr($NF,length($NF)-5)}1' file
```

Here we keep only last 6 characters of the last field, while semicolon is the field separator. If there is nothing else in front of that `*ID*#`, then we keep all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything before the first *:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{sub(/^[^*]*/,"",$NF)}1' file
```

Output:

```
2020-01-11 01:01:01;test;test123;*123*#
```

Comment: This works, unfortunately it revealed an error where the value in ID2 can be also just "1", "2", "3"..

Comment: There is no error as that would implicate faulty code. The script complies with your definition of "ID2" and if you feed it data that doesn't comply with your own definition, it produces output that may or may not satisfy you. That said, I'd use @thanasisp's solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following tested and written with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/[0-9]{12}\[[0-9]+\]>/) && /\*[0-9]{3}\*#/{
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/[0-9]{12}\[[0-9]+\]>/) && /\*[0-9]{3}\*#/{         ##Using match function to match regex in it, what regex does is: It matches digits(12 in number) then [ then digits(continuously coming) and ] Also checking condition if line ends with *3 digits *
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)      ##If above condition is TRUE then printing sub-string from 1st character to RSTART-1 and then sub-string from RSTART+RLENGTH value to till last of line.
}
'  Input_file                                                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I tried this, but it only return rows, where ID2 = \*[0-9]{3}\*#.

Comment: @OndřejČejka, with shown samples in worked fine for me, I have explained it with details please do let me know on same if you find anything in it, its written as per shown samples and conditions only cheers.